# Find an array element from the value of an element of the hashes it contains

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I'm try to sort an array of hashes `@aoh`, and at the moment I extract certain keys' values and sort this list. I extract the value for the key `description` from each hash.

Now I want to be able to identify which element of the array corresponds to a given value of a hash element.

I think I need to use hash references, but how to do it?

Example of my code is below

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my %h1 = ('description', 'great one');
my %h2 = ('description', 'fool');
my %h3 = ('description', 'easy');
my %h4 = ('description', 'intermediate');
my %h5 = ('description', 'hard');
my %h6 = ('description', 'beauty');
my %h7 = ('description', 'dark');
my %h8 = ('description', 'yellow');
my %h9 = ('description', 'red');

my @aoh = ( %h1, %h2, %h3, %h4, %h5, %h6, %h7, %h8, %h9 );

my @vals;

while ( my ($index, $value) = each @aoh ) {

    if ( $aoh[$index] ne 'description' ) {
        push @vals, $aoh[$index];
    }
}

my @sorted = sort @vals;

printf "@sorted\n";
```

In an result I would like to get `@sorted_aoh` like this:

```
@sorted_aoh = (
    'description'->'beauty',
    'description'->'dark',
    'description'->'easy',
    'description'->'fool',
    'description'->'great one',
    'description'->'one',
    'description'->'hard',
    'description'->'intermediate',
    'description'->'red',
);
```

Comment: If you need to "_identify which element of the array corresponds to a given value of a hash element_" then you don't need a sorted array that you are asking about, but rather a lookup mechanism like in Borodin's answer.  Also, I'd suggest to read through some docs on these things. Tutorial on references is [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and for complex data structures there is the cookbook [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

Comment: @zdim, Thanks for the tip) I will study these docs

Comment: Just in case ... I take it that your "_description_" is in reality varied text, and not always the same word. But, if by any chance you actually have hashes with a single pair and each has the _same word_ for the key then you should change the design (no need for two data structures, but use either an array or a hash).  Also, it appears awkward to sort the array by hash _values_ -- how are you going to look them up?  How are you going to retrieve the element for, say, the value `hard`? You'd have to iterate, denying the purpose of the hash.  Perhaps you should explain the purpose of all this.

Comment: @zdim, data structure represented in this case is an abstraction and a stripped-down version of the real data (and as shown by the discussion - not the most successful, unfortunately). In real task it's more complicated, but (as I thought) to clarify the matter - should be enough of these data.

Comment: Alright, thanks for confirming that :)  I am still unsure about the utility of an array sorted by hash values, but that may have been lost in abstraction -- you know your real data and problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code uses an array of hash references and sorts it according to the value of `description` key. A backslash before hash variable name (`\%h1`) represents a reference to that hash. The `sort` function uses a custom comparison block, lookup `perldoc -f sort` for more information about it and `perldoc perlcheat` to learn how to work with references.

```
        #!/usr/bin/perl
        use warnings;
        use strict;

        my %h1 = ('description', 'greate one');
        my %h2 = ('description', 'fool');
        my %h3 = ('description', 'easy');
        my %h4 = ('description', 'intermediate');
        my %h5 = ('description', 'hard');
        my %h6 = ('description', 'beauty');
        my %h7 = ('description', 'dark');
        my %h8 = ('description', 'yellow');
        my %h9 = ('description', 'red');
        my @aoh = (\%h1, \%h2, \%h3, \%h4, \%h5, \%h6, \%h7, \%h8, \%h9);

        my @sorted = sort { $a->{description} cmp $b->{description} } @aoh;
        use Data::Dumper;
        print Dumper(\@sorted);
```

Comment: In context of your solutionwas one sub-question: how to dinamically @aoh transform to array of hash references.

Simple loop transformation doesn't work in my hand! That's need to `(%h1, %h2, %h3, %h4, %h5, %h6, %h7, %h8, %h9)` transform to `(\%h1, \%h2, \%h3, \%h4, \%h5, \%h6, \%h7, \%h8, \%h9)`

Comment: @John I do not know any nice way to do that. Inside PERL lists, hashes are are not distinguishable because they are automatically broken into a sequence of keys and values. You may like to use hashrefs from the start like `my $h0 = { description => "yo value" };`.

Comment: The *reference operator* `\ `  is *distributive*, so `my @aoh = ( \%h1, \%h2, \%h3, \%h4, \%h5, \%h6, \%h7, \%h8, \%h9 )` may be more conveniently written as `my @aoh = \ ( %h1, %h2, %h3, %h4, %h5, %h6, %h7, %h8, %h9 );`

Comment: @Borodin, thanks, that's good and important addition to understanding of the case

Answer (score 2):

As has been explained, your array `@aoh` isn't an array of hashes, it's just an array of scalar data. It looks like this

```
(
  "description",
  "great one",
  "description",
  "fool",
  "description",
  "easy",
  "description",
  "intermediate",
  "description",
  "hard",
  "description",
  "beauty",
  "description",
  "dark",
  "description",
  "yellow",
  "description",
  "red",
)
```

The identity of the hashes has been lost, and the data is flattened into a single list. Perl implements nested structures by using *references*

You don't say where your data is coming from, but rather than starting with a number of individually-named hashes and then copying their references into an array, it is probably best to use the elements of the array directly, so `$h1{description}` becomes `$aoh[0]{description}` etc.

This solution starts with `@aoh` built like this, so there are no named hashes.

*(By the way, names like `%h1` and `@aoh` are very poor. Identifiers should describe the notion of their contents, so `%people`, or `@sales_figures`, not the nature of data structure that they are. The leading `%` or `@` in Perl tells you that anyway, but the same applies to identifiers in any language.)*

If you often find yourself needing to access what value corresponds to another in a program, then it's usually best to build a separate hash to store that relationship. Here I've built hash `%desc_to_index` which relates the values of each hash's `description` element to the index of the array where it's found

I've dumped the resulting structure at the end so that you can see what it contains

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use List::Util 'max';

my @aoh = (
    { description => 'great one' },
    { description => 'fool' },
    { description => 'easy' },
    { description => 'intermediate' },
    { description => 'hard' },
    { description => 'beauty' },
    { description => 'dark' },
    { description => 'yellow' },
    { description => 'red' },
);

my %desc_to_index = map { $aoh[$_]{description} => $_ } 0 .. $#aoh;

{
    my $len = max map { length } keys %desc_to_index;

    for my $desc ( sort keys %desc_to_index ) {
        printf "%*s => %d\n", $len, $desc, $desc_to_index{$desc};
    }
}
```

#### output

```
      beauty => 5
        dark => 6
        easy => 2
        fool => 1
   great one => 0
        hard => 4
intermediate => 3
         red => 8
      yellow => 7
```

I hope you'll agree that the `map` statement that builds `%desc_to_index` is neat and concise, but it may baffle you. If you prefer, you may write a for loop instead which does the same thing, like this

```perl
my %desc_to_index;

for my $i ( 0 .. $#aoh ) {
    my $desc = $aoh[$i]{description};
    $desc_to_index{$desc} = $i;
}
```

which produces identical results

Note also that your loop

```perl
while ( my ($index, $value) = each @aoh ) { ... }
```

uses `each` on an array, which is unusual and unnecessary here. It is also unavailable before Perl 5 v12, and `each` can produce awkward errors if the loop is exited prematurely

You don't need `each` because you never use the value of `$value`, preferring `$aoh[$index]` instead, which is much more common. Your loop would be better written with a simple `for` loop like this

```perl
for my $index ( 0 .. $#aoh ) { ... }
```

Answer (score -1):

how about leveraging unique key name across ll hasesh

```
use Data::Dumper;
my %h1 = ('description', 'great one');
my %h2 = ('description', 'fool');
my %h3 = ('description', 'easy');
my %h4 = ('description', 'intermediate');
my %h5 = ('description', 'hard');
my %h6 = ('description', 'beauty');
my %h7 = ('description', 'dark');
my %h8 = ('description', 'yellow');
my %h9 = ('description', 'red');
my @aoh =  sort map { values $_ } (\%h1, \%h2, \%h3, \%h4, \%h5, \%h6, \%h7, \%h8, \%h9);
my @hash = map { {"description" => $_}} @aoh;
print  Dumper(\@hash);
```

Comment: oh, thanks.. This solution looks not so universal as from@pii_ke, because if i do a little bit complex for every hashes, output of this code remains the same (only with pair 'description'->value).  Maybe it's looks so for my, beginner position only

Comment: @JohnSmith: You must put *all your requirements* into your question. If you want to add something non-trivial to your question then you should write a new question. It is unfair to accept one answer over another because it happens to fulfil requirements that you didn't specify.

Comment: k , agreed , @JohnSmith , but that answer again can't be universal being hard check for key 'description' , i did mention in my comments abt leveraging unique key among all other hasesh.

Comment: @Birodin, my original question was about how to return the entire hash via using hash value of one of its key.. I suppose that, as tests have shown, using a different array of hashes (with many key-value pairs) in the decision still does not return the entire hash